# Purrr map over splited dataframe to get AUROC for each group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I asked this question already here ([Purrr map over splitted training-dataframe to get auroc for each model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68133161/purrr-map-over-splitted-training-dataframe-to-get-auroc-for-each-model?noredirect=1#comment120434363_68133161)), but the data was really bad and the question maybe a bit confusing. In addition I found a way to resolve this, but it does not feel like a good way.

So the issue is the following. I split a dataframe based on its `geology`-column. I then want to predict the column `trigger` using two other columns in the training dataframe. And I want to do this for each geology (each element - dataframe - of the list).
I then want to predict this model on a new testdataframe and compute the AUROC for each geology.

Here is the training data:

```
# the training data
structure(list(p3 = c(5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2.8999999165535, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 17.5999999046326, 0, 0, 0.899999976158142, 10.0000000149012, 
1.79999995231628, 0, 8.80000019073486, 0, 0, 11.8999999761581, 
0, 9.60000026226044, 5.19999980926514, 11.7000002861023, 20.0999999046326, 
34.6000008583069, 0, 8.70000028610229, 33.8000000119209, 2.40000009536743, 
17, 27, 36.7999992370605, 0, 15.8999997973442, 0.300000011920929, 
7.69999980926514, 0, 0.899999976158142, 1.5, 0.300000011920929, 
3.50000002980232, 51.3999991416931, 6.09999990463257, 0.400000005960464, 
22, 65.3000020980835), p15 = c(34.2999999374151, 10.4999997392297, 
8.30000010877848, 69.4999992623925, 1.30000001192093, 0, 62.3999992161989, 
71.8999995738268, 32.6999994888902, 4, 0, 0.400000005960464, 
35.699999935925, 24.1000001206994, 0, 53.8999998271465, 41.8999992236495, 
37.8999994322658, 24.0999998524785, 65.5999999046326, 0, 0, 20.5000002905726, 
75.4000002145767, 68.1999989748001, 45.9000007808208, 180.999998480082, 
70.5000009462237, 112.099999666214, 11.3000001907349, 88.0999987274408, 
103.499998867512, 100.399998664856, 59.9999995827675, 200.699998855591, 
21.2999993562698, 47.1999997496605, 42.1999989748001, 58.6000000834465, 
161.299998879433, 43.3999999314547, 110.899999141693, 73.9000004529953, 
46.7999998703599, 25.7999995350838, 21.1000004559755, 86.100000500679, 
15.8999998569489, 5.3999999538064, 143.399998903275), trigger = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
    geology = c("Sedimentary rocks", "Crystalline basement", 
    "Sedimentary rocks", "Sedimentary rocks", "Porphyry", "Porphyry", 
    "Porphyry", "Sedimentary rocks", "Sedimentary rocks", "Crystalline basement", 
    "Calcschists with ophiolites", "Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", 
    "Sedimentary rocks", "Porphyry", "Porphyry", "Crystalline basement", 
    "Crystalline basement", "Sedimentary rocks", "Crystalline basement", 
    "Sedimentary rocks", "Porphyry", "Crystalline basement", 
    "Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", 
    "Sedimentary rocks", "Porphyry", "Sedimentary rocks", "Crystalline basement", 
    "Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", "Porphyry", 
    "Calcschists with ophiolites", "Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", 
    "Sedimentary rocks", "Porphyry", "Crystalline basement", 
    "Porphyry", "Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", 
    "Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", "Calcschists with ophiolites", 
    "Plutonite", "Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", 
    "Porphyry", "Sedimentary rocks")), row.names = c(NA, -50L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and here the test data

```
structure(list(p3 = c(6.40000009536743, 0, 0, 16.3000003397465, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1.5, 29.1000003814697, 7.49999982118607, 3.5, 
18.3999996185303, 2.69999990612268, 11.3000001907349, 0, 2, 9.5, 
0, 10.1999998092651, 0, 3.60000005364418, 0, 5.29999995231628, 
112.599998474121, 118.099997758865, 54.8999996185303, 72.8000011444092, 
79.9000015258789, 88.7000015377998, 0, 54.6000022888184, 144.599998474121, 
111.200000762939, 7.10000009834766, 32.0999999046326, 0.5, 5.3999999165535, 
0.300000011920929, 0, 36.7999982833862, 101.599998474121, 121.699998855591, 
31.0999994277954, 66.8000020980835, 139.200000762939, 9.50000011920929, 
135.300003051758, 110.900001525879), p15 = c(12.3999996185303, 
63.8000009655952, 20.7000007629395, 121.299998179078, 10.4000001549721, 
27.1999999880791, 49.5000003874302, 13.3000001907349, 31.3999998569489, 
15.4000002890825, 64.3999997377396, 25.1000001430511, 43.6999994516373, 
50.799999833107, 35.1999998092651, 35.1999998837709, 67.1000003442168, 
19.400000333786, 49.300000667572, 21.3999996706843, 75.600000411272, 
38.700000859797, 30.2999994754791, 14.9000003933907, 53.2000011727214, 
137.900000333786, 0.100000001490116, 119.300001859665, 139.700000107288, 
147.799997329712, 45.3000004068017, 56.5000000670552, 47.7999995946884, 
2.90000009536743, 139.499999403954, 26.6999999284744, 6.5, 149.700001835823, 
210.299998342991, 114.499999642372, 3.60000002384186, 60.099999524653, 
97.5999984890223, 153.100000120699, 245.299996376038, 123.49999922514, 
3.70000004768372, 90.5999985486269, 49.1000001132488, 138.599999785423
), trigger = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), groups = structure(list(
    trigger = c(FALSE, TRUE), .rows = structure(list(1:25, 26:50), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I now did to fit the logistic regression model `trigger ~ p3 + 15` for each geology and get the auroc for each class is the following:

```
res = train %>% split(., .$geology) %>%
  map( ~ glm(trigger ~ p3 + p15, data = .x, family = "binomial")) %>%
  map( ~ predict(.x, newdata = test, type = "response")) %>%
  map(function(x) {
    df = data.frame(ref = test$trigger)
    df[["pred"]] = x
    df
  }) %>% map_dfr(function(x) {
   auc = as.numeric(roc(ref ~ pred, data = x)$auc)
  }) %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "geology", values_to="auc")
```

But there are some parts (the `function(x){...}`) that I would like to replace with a more concise `purrr`-style syntax. I am having some troubles to figure my head arround the `.x`, the `.` and when to use the `{}` to prevent the result passed into a tibble (maybe necessary at some point).
So how could I achieve the same result, however omitting the `function(x)` syntax?

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `split()` you could use `group_by` and `summarise`. At first list columns are a bit tricky to work with, but once you get used to them they are super useful in many situations. I would try something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

train %>% 
  group_by(geology) %>% 
  summarise(
    model = list(glm(trigger ~ p3 + p15, data = cur_data(), family = "binomial")),
    yhat = map(model, ~predict(.x, newdata = test, type = "response")),
    auc = map_dbl(yhat, ~pROC::roc(test$trigger, .x)$auc)
  ) %>% 
  select(geology, auc)

## A tibble: 5 x 2
#  geology                       auc
#  <chr>                       <dbl>
# 1 Calcschists with ophiolites 0.794
# 2 Crystalline basement        0.84 
# 3 Plutonite                   0.5  
# 4 Porphyry                    0.864
# 5 Sedimentary rocks           0.912
```

or alternatively without creating the temporary columns

```
train %>% 
  group_by(geology) %>% 
  summarise(
    auc = glm(trigger ~ p3 + p15, data = cur_data(), family = "binomial") %>% 
      predict(newdata = test, type = "response") %>% 
      pROC::roc(test$trigger, .) %>% `$`("auc") %>% as.numeric()
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: wow, thank you very much!! I yet did not find the super advantage of using list-columns for me and its a little hard to wrap the head around them I think. But I am sure they have lots of use cases:)

Comment: I ended up using this approach a lot:) So thank you very much again! I constanly use list columns now;) 
One thing I was wondering in this answer is why one needs to put  the `glm(...)` in a  `list()`. I means it feels nice as I want a list as output. But can't I somehow use `map` to get a model for each group?:)

Answer (score 2):

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(pROC)

res <- train %>% 
  split(., .$geology) %>%
  map( ~ glm(trigger ~ p3 + p15, data = .x, family = "binomial")) %>%
  map( ~ predict(.x, newdata = test, type = "response")) %>%
  map( ~ data.frame(ref = test$trigger, pred = .x)) %>% 
  map_dfc( ~ as.numeric(roc(ref ~ pred, data = .x)$auc)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "geology", values_to = "auc")
```

The `.` is the data passed on from the pipe so that it can be used in the function. The `purrr` functions instead provide the `.x` argument as the data passed into the function.

Because you use `pivot_longer`, you want one column per result, so I've used `map_dfc`. To convert from the `function(x)` style, I think the best way is to think about what you want to return, in your case a data.frame and a value, so you can write it also in the `~` style.

Comment: Great answer, just to add: Other than `.x` and `.y`, `purrr` also accepts `.` (!), `...`, `..1`, `..2` and so on. Combining the magrittr pipe with purrr style notation can be ambiguous, which was part of the motivation for introducing the native pipe `|>` as I understand.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer!:) That really helped a lot

Comment: @ktiu your completely right, I've left it out because I find the `.` always so hard to spot and prefer the longer names for clarity

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve this, see my approach below. Note, however, that using functions in a map-chain such as this can be a really useful technique, and should not be avoided out of principle.

```
library(purrr)

train %>%
  split(~ geology) %>%
  map(~ glm(trigger ~ p3 + p15, data = .x, family = "binomial")) %>%
  map(~ predict(.x, newdata = test, type = "response")) %>%
  map(~ data.frame(ref = test$trigger, pred = .x)) %>%
  map(~ pROC::roc(ref ~ pred, data = .x)$auc) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  tibble::tibble(geology = names(.), auc = .)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  geology                       auc
  <chr>                       <dbl>
1 Calcschists with ophiolites 0.794
2 Crystalline basement        0.84 
3 Plutonite                   0.5  
4 Porphyry                    0.864
5 Sedimentary rocks           0.912
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Good to know that using functions in such a chain is a valid option. I thought it would be kind of a ugly work-around for those who do not know how to use `map` properly...